# Is there something wrong with my mix-blend-mode code snippet?

Tags: css, blending, webflow, mix-blend-mode

I’ve been trying emulate (in Webflow) this nifty 'fluid text hover' from the following codepen: https://codepen.io/robin-dela/pen/KKPYoBq

As you can see, there is a fair amount of HTML, CSS (SCSS) and JS (Babel), but I believe the pertinent code snippet to be the following:

```
<style>
body {
    position: fixed;
    height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

canvas {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}

.mask {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 2;
    background: white;
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100vw;
    mix-blend-mode: screen;
    /* THE mix-blend-mode ABOVE DISPLAYS IN RED */
}

svg {
    width: 90%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

</style>
```

When I publish my site, the 'CREATIVE' text displays, but without the interactive fluid element. I’m almost certain it’s something to do with the mix-blend-mode, as that is the only code showing up in red. I’ve seen similar questions asked on here, and have tried all the methods offered (changing the body background to white, as opposed to transparent; adding the code as a code block rather than the Inside  tag, but nothing has as yet made it work. I’d really appreciate any help.

My Webflow site read-only can be found here:
https://preview.webflow.com/preview/hen-ry?utm_medium=preview_link&utm_source=designer&utm_content=hen-ry&preview=f7f278a8af346d820c843647397c8d76&pageId=6238983c269c21e6d0507afe&workflow=preview

Comment: The webflow link has mix-blend-mode: normal applied

Comment: I can't see your canvas element... are you doing this the same as the codepen?

Comment: That's strange, when I follow that link I can see mid-blend-mode: screen applied. 
In the Webflow page, my CSS is in the Inside <head> tag, the JS is in the Before </body> tag (both of these found in the FLUID TEXT page settings. The HTML is in the HTML Embed 2 (within the body block) - which can be accessed via the Navigator.

Comment: The canvas element is located in the FLUID TEXT page settings - if you scroll down, you'll see the Inside <head> tag, which contains the CSS (including the canvas element)

Comment: I mean I can't see the <canvas> element, I can see your styles

Comment: Can't see the script before the closing body tag that is supposed to create the canvas etc.

Comment: Oh, I hear you. I copied the codepen into the custom code of the page, so I don't actually think I have a <canvas> element. Would you advise creating one?

Comment: The code you've copy pasted creates one, the code is what is not loading. Load the code. Webflow is not loading the code.

Comment: I'm a little confused, (very new to this all), apologies Zach. I'm almost certain that I've copied everything perfectly from the codepen - and, more confusingly, I can't see any <canvas> elements on the codepen that didn't copy over which I would be able to thus load on after-the-fact. Are you advising me to load a <canvas> and </canvas> at the start and end of my HTML code block? Or are we seeing different things in the codepen (?) Or am I missing your point entirely, if so genuinely sorry.

Comment: I can understand you're a beginner, you don't have to apologise. I have no idea what webflow is doing with your code, but when I open devtools, the script tag with the javascript from the codepen DOES NOT LOAD. This has nothing to do with your HTML. The javascript adds the canvas HTML. Ask webflow why they aren't loading your script.

Answer (score 0):

You're probably missing the js file. If you click the little settings button at the top of the JS section, you will see a file called https://robindelaporte.fr/codepen/bundle.js, if you have not loaded this then it won't work.